# Open Set and Interior Point

Tags: general-topology, analysis

*Recall*:

- $U$ is *open* if and only if for any $x\in U$ there is an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\left( x-\varepsilon ,x+\varepsilon \right)\subseteq U$
- Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. We say that an element $x$ of $X$ is an *interior point* of $X$ if there is an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\left( x-\varepsilon ,x+\varepsilon \right)\subseteq X$.

**My question is**: 1) Can we say that if $U$ is open then for any element $u\in U$ is an interior point?

2) Also, can we say if $U$ has interior points then $U$ is open?

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) No. A set is open if and only if it contains only interior points.

Comment: The first point only applies where $U \subseteq \Bbb R$.

Comment: @MPW you should make that as an answer.

Comment: @KennyLau : Done!

Comment: Substitute the definition in the second bullet point into the first bullet point, giving us "$U$ is open if and only if every $x \in U$ is an interior point of $U$".

Comment: @MPW But you said that ''if and only if'' hence, we can say 2) is trure.

Comment: @MPW Can't we?.

Comment: @MPW For an example, $A$ is apple if and only if $B$ is beer. Hence, if $A$ is apple then $B$ is beer. Also, we can say if $B$ is beer then $A$ is apple, right? Thus,My comment (for 2)) is trure as your firs comment?

Comment: No. It is open if and only if it contains **ONLY** interior points, not interior points and boundary points. Consider the interval $[0,1]$ in the real line. It contains interior points (all points except $0$ and $1$), but it isn't open. The reason is that it also contains $0$ and $1$, which are boundary points, not interior points (do you see why?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, because if $u\in U$ then, since $U$ is open, then, by definition of open set, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(u-\varepsilon,u+\varepsilon)\subset U$. And this means that $u$ is an interior point of $U$.
2. No. Take $U=[-1,1]$. Then $U$ is not open (because there is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)\subset U$), but $0$ *is* an interior point of $U$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Kahler You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes; (2) No.

It is true in general that a set is open if and only if it contains only interior points.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes by definition.

(2) No, since $U$ being an open set requires all $u \in U$ to be interior points of $U$.